# Sorting algorithm using divide and conquer

Tags: algorithm

This is like a stock marketing problem, I am confused that the question is asking about how to get everyday's maximum profit? I only know that the algorithm's time complexity can be O(n) or O(n log2 n).

The input is A, an array of stock prices. For day i, the best trade is the maximum profit that can be achieved by buying at day i and selling on a subsequent day. For convenience, you can define the best trade for the last day to simply be −A[n] (because if you buy on the last day, you cannot sell and you lost all your money).
Give the pseudocode of an algorithm that returns an array containing the maximum profit for every day in A.

Update: I understand how to get the maximum profit now, and I can use the similar algorithm as the merge sort that divide and conquer to find this maximum profit. My question is what's another method (algorithm) that use time complexity O(n) to find the maximum profit or how can I approach in this way?

Comment: it is basically telling you to find the MIN and MAX of each day's trade. you buy at MIN(i) and sell at MAX(i+1) except for the last day where you don't buy anymore.

Comment: Every day identify the stock `S` where `price(S, n+1)/price(S, n)` is as big as possible.  If it is less than 1, sit that day out.  Otherwise buy as much of S as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you can think of this problem is using one for loop since it's O(n), I can give you some hints:

```
    for i from 0 to n:
        if (A[i] < A[min])   // find the minimum value of stock
          min = i;
        profit = A[i] - A[min]    // get the profit
        if (profit > maxProfit) {   // compares the profits
          maxProfit = profit   // always update the max profit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you buy on day `i`, the maximum profit you can make is `Amax(i) - A[i]`,
where `Amax(i)` is the highest price that occurs *after* day `i`.
My reading of the algorithm's specification is that you are to construct and return the array `M` whose entries are defined by `M[i] = Amax(i) - A[i]`.

The highest price that occurs after day `i` is the greater of
`A[i+i]` and the highest price that occurs after day `i + 1`.

The last paragraph gives you a recursive relationship, except that unlike
the "typical" recursion you might see, the `i`th value depends on the
`i + 1`st value rather than the other way around.
But fortunately for you, you already know that the `n`th value and
every later value is 0, that is, after day `n` you will get 0 for your stock.
So you only need to figure out the values for days
1, 2, ..., `n - 1`, which you can do in O(n) time.
And each time you find one of these values, `Amax(i)`, you can set one of the entries of `M` using `M[i] = Amax(i) - A[i]`.

---

If you want to find the maximum profit that can be made by buying one share of stock on any single day and selling on any subsequent day, one time
(though this is not required by the problem statement, as far as I can see), you just have to find the maximum value in `M`, which you can do in O(n) time.

If your goal is to make the maximum profit possible by a series of actions, buying and selling stock, the best you can do is to buy as many shares as you can afford whenever the stock is at a local minimum (assuming infinite price before the first day) and sell everything whenever it reaches a local maximum price. You can identify all the local minimums and maximums in O(n) time, scanning `A` in either direction, and given a starting amount of money, you can compute the maximum overall profit in O(n) time using the list of local minimums and maximums of `A`. (But this does not use the array that the original problem statement asked you to construct, because that array does not account for the number of shares bought nor the possibility of multiple transactions.)

Remember that if each pass of a two-pass algorithm takes O(n) time, the algorithm as a whole takes O(n) time.

Comment: thanks David, but I don't understand that how can I make sure the day I buy my stock is the minimum price? (ex, Day1($2), Day2($1), Day3($10), if I buy on day one, then I can't make the most profit) and to check the minimum I need O(n), to check the maximum after day i, I need O(n). would it become O(n^2)?

Comment: I don't see where in the spec for the program it says you have to buy at the minimum price. It just says to return an array, which if I read the spec correctly, tells you what happens if you buy on day `i` and sell at the maximum price after that. There are other strategies you could follow to better optimize your buying and selling of stocks, but this problem does not ask for those strategies.